# How do I get the current x and y position of the mouse cursor in a Dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

I want to retrieve the x and y of the point over the mouse pointer. How can I do that? The callbacks are always about the points, and I may be with the cursor over a free region.

Comment: Is this helpful http://dygraphs.com/tests/dygraph-many-points-benchmark.html ? pls let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it

```
function getElementTop ( Elem ) 
{ 
 var elem;

if ( document.getElementById ) 
{   
    elem = document.getElementById ( Elem );
} 
else if ( document.all ) 
{
    elem = document.all[Elem];
}           

yPos = elem.offsetTop;
tempEl = elem.offsetParent;

while ( tempEl != null ) 
{
    yPos += tempEl.offsetTop;
    tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
}  

return yPos;
}   

function getElementLeft ( Elem ) 
{
var elem;

if ( document.getElementById ) 
{
    var elem = document.getElementById ( Elem );
} 
else if ( document.all )
{
    var elem = document.all[Elem];
}           

xPos = elem.offsetLeft;
tempEl = elem.offsetParent;         

while ( tempEl != null ) 
{
    xPos += tempEl.offsetLeft;
    tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
}           
return xPos;
}


var graphOnmousemove = function(arg,evt) {
console.log(evt);
var x = evt.pageX - getElementLeft("graph_data_div2");
var y = evt.pageY - getElementTop("graph_data_div2");
x = livePlotVtx2.toDataXCoord(x);
y = livePlotVtx2.toDataYCoord(y);
if (Ext.getCmp("graphTooltip") && Ext.getCmp("graphTooltip").body) { 
    Ext.getCmp("graphTooltip").body.dom.innerHTML = x.toFixed(2) + "," + y.toFixed(2);
    Ext.getCmp("graphTooltip").show();
}
};
```

then I added the onmousemove event to the div onmousemove(this, event)